# Simple layout engine with python bindings

Tags: python, layout, graphics

I am looking for a way to arrange graphical objects on a canvas according certain rules. The rule set has to include absolute/relative positioning, minimal and maximal sizes of the objects, e.g. elements in a table. What I currently have in mind is a limited subset of HTML+CSS or something similar to the layout part of Qt4. Ideally I would like to feed my object and layout rules to the engine and get the absolute sizes and positions as a result.

To clarify: I am looking for a software/library that can accomplish this task, ideally a small python library (which speaks against a full-featured HTML engine)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, or if you're just looking for proposals on how to get started...

Comment: Erik: Thanks for the comment, I hope my last edit clarified my question.

Answer (score -1):

personaly i would use the layout managers because when you use gui designers they make a lot of "bad" code.

But if you want to go for a designer try qt designer. theres lot of videos on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOuCuLHmk3o) explaining how to use it and documentation. `pyuic4` can convert the `.ui` (qt designer files) files to `.py` files.